# Query a collection based on an association, and then return the whole association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord, arel

It's hard to squeeze this whole question into a short title. I have a Records model, and each record `has many :tags`, and `has many :words, through: :tags`. Also, the Word table has a `string` column, holding the string form of the word.

I'm trying to build a search query, so that users can search for records with certain words and see all the words that each returned record has. However, so far when I have the queried Records only the words that I queried on are included. I need to show all the words (even the un-searched words) for each record. But I can't figure this out and it's been a week or two of reading SO questions and Rails docs. I've tried using plain rails ActiveRecord stuff, and I tried using Arel tables. I have one working solution, but that involves building an array of the plucked ids of all the found Records, and finding them again, which just puts a bad taste in my mouth. Anyway, here's what I have:

`record.rb`

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :words, through: :tags

  # this is the kind of query that I want
  # +search+ is an array of words, ex: %w{chick fil a}
  # however, `scope.first.words.count != scope.first.words(true).count`
  # that is, the first record's words are not all force reloaded automatically
  def self.that_have_all_words_in_rails(search)
    scope = includes(:words)
    search.each do |search_word|
      scope = scope.where(words: { string: search_word })
    end
    scope
  end

  # I also tried this in arel, but it seems to give the same result as above
  def self.that_have_all_words_in_arel(search)
    scope = joins(:words)
    search.each do |search_word|
      scope = scope.where(word_table[:string].eq(search_word))
    end
    scope.includes(:words)
  end

  def word_table
    Record.arel_table
  end

  # This is the only working version that I have, but it seems
  # sloppy to use the record_ids array like this.
  # That could be a 1000+ element array!
  def self.that_have_all_words_in(search)
    records = includes(:words)
    record_ids = search.inject(pluck(:id)) do |ids, search_word|
      ids & records.where(words: { string: search_word }).pluck(:id)
    end
    where(id: record_ids)
  end
```

`word.rb`

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :records, through: :tags
end
```

So, any ideas on how to be able to perform a query like:

```
Record.that_have_all_words_in(['chick', 'fil', 'a']).first.words
```

so that I get all the words of the first record, including words that are not 'chick' or 'fil' or 'a', without having to force reload with `first.words(true)`?

Thanks.

**Update**: the relevant parts of my schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150727041434) do
  create_table "records", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "tags", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "word_id"
    t.integer  "record_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "words", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "string"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

Also, I'm using sqlite3 for my db.

Comment: Can you include your schema.rb for the relevant tables / columns?

Comment: Also, please tag with the db you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom join with [aliased](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/alias.php) tables to match the search conditions:

```
def self.where_tagged_words_match_strings(search)
  search.uniq!
  joins("INNER JOIN tags mtags ON mtags.record_id = records.id INNER JOIN words mwords ON mwords.id = mtags.word_id")
    .where("mwords.string IN (?)", search).group("records.id").having("COUNT(DISTINCT mwords.string) = #{search.length}")
end
```

**ETA** This query should select records with words matching an arbitrary search array. It does this by selecting records whose words match *any* of the strings in the array, then grouping by records' id, selecting only those having a number of matching strings equal to the number of strings queried.

You can then chain this with `includes(:words)` to get *all* of the words associated, since the query above uses the aliased `mwords`:

```
Record.where_tagged_words_match_strings(search).includes(:words)
```

Relatedly, while all of the above should work in SQLite, I highly recommend that you switch to a more powerful and production-ready SQL database such as MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you SO much. This didn't work exactly, but it gave me everything I needed to work off of. The solution given works with only one search word, but not with multiple search words (which never returned anything. I think with multiple search words it was looking for one Word object with every search term as it's string).

Comment: By the way, what worked for me was: `def where_tagged_words_match_strings(search);
      records = joins("INNER JOIN tags mtags ON mtags.record_id = records.id INNER JOIN words mwords ON mwords.id = mtags.word_id");
      records = search.inject(records) do |scope, word|
        records.where("mwords.string = ?", word);
      end;
      records.includes(:words);
    end`

Comment: Doh, you're right! Your solution works as well, but does a lot of the logic in Ruby. I try to keep as much logic as possible in the database, since its *much* faster. I've edited with a correct solution that uses GROUP BY and HAVING. Let me know if it works for you...

Comment: Yep, your new solution works perfectly. Thanks a ton! (In fact, I found out that my commented solution has a typo, and once the typo was fixed my solution has the same problem as your first solution.)